# Which is the fastest decoder for jpeg full-scale decoding?

Tags: c++, jpeg, performance, decoder

Which is the fastest decoder for jpeg full-scale decoding ?
I want to accelerate my apps' jpeg decoding speed, how can I do this?
I am using libjpeg now, it is a bit slow, is there any one faster than libjpeg?
I do not need partical decoding.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which is the fastest, but these should be faster than IJG's libjpeg:

[free] [libjpeg-turbo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/)

[cost] [Intel Performance Primitives (IPP) library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/)

Comment: There is an free version for IPP available now but IPP does no longer support JPEG instead [Intel Media SDK](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK) should be used which is Open Source and available under MIT license.